# Does Kafka Streams ignore unprefixed ProducerConfig properties?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka Streams configuration looks like this:

```
Properties c = new Properties();
c.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, config.kafka.applicationId);
c.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, config.kafka.bootstrapServers);
...
c.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, config.kafka.maxRequestSize);
c.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

Accidentally I came across [this page](https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#id2) and was reminded of the [`StreamsConfig.producerPrefix` method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L787-L797). I didn't apply this method to my config. Does this mean the ProducerConfig settings in the above example are ignored?

[A quick look to the code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L1101-L1116) makes me think my assumption is correct. Can someone confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't prefix it, the config will be passed to all clients, ie, `acks=all` will be set for the consumer and producer config. The consumer will not know this config and log a WARN message. Also, some configs are valid producer and consumer configs -- prefixing allows to set different values for producer and consumer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks! I didn't see a WARN message so far. As I understand the code, the provided properties are filtered based on `ProducerConfig.configNames()`. If the config is valid for both producer and consumer it will be used in both clients, otherwise it will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I panicked for no reason: both flavours of properties are accepted. Following 2 lines have the same effect:

```
properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG), "all");
```

The [`getClientPropsWithPrefix` method of Kafka Streams](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L1137-L1142) combines the provided producer properties (`ProducerConfig.configNames()`) and the prefixed properties (`PRODUCER_PREFIX`).

---

For the record, I wrote the following test class and added a debug breakpoint in `KafkaProducer#doSend` method and traced back to `StreamsConfig#getProducerConfigs`:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.EmbeddedKafkaCluster;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.IntegrationTestUtils;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ProducerPropertiesPrefixIntegrationTest {

  @ClassRule
  public static final EmbeddedKafkaCluster CLUSTER = new EmbeddedKafkaCluster(1);

  private static final String INPUT_TOPIC = "input";
  private static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "output";

  @Test
  public void testPrefix() throws Exception {
    CLUSTER.createTopic(INPUT_TOPIC, 1, 1);
    CLUSTER.createTopic("ouput", 3, 1);

    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    streamsBuilder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-app");
    p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, CLUSTER.bootstrapServers());
    p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());
    p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());

    p.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
    p.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "2048");

    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), p);
    kafkaStreams.start();

    IntegrationTestUtils.produceKeyValuesSynchronously(INPUT_TOPIC,
       Collections.singleton(KeyValue.pair("test", "value")), 
       getProducerConfig(), CLUSTER.time);

    List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords =
       IntegrationTestUtils.waitUntilMinRecordsReceived(
          getConsumerConfig(), OUTPUT_TOPIC, 1, 10000);
    assertThat(consumerRecords).hasSize(1);
    assertThat(consumerRecords.get(0).key()).isEqualTo("test");
    assertThat(consumerRecords.get(0).value()).isEqualTo("value");

    kafkaStreams.close(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
  }

  private Properties getProducerConfig() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, CLUSTER.bootstrapServers());
    p.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    p.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return producerProps;
  }

  private Properties getConsumerConfig() {
    Properties c = new Properties();
    c.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, CLUSTER.bootstrapServers());
    c.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
    c.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    c.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return c;
  }
}
```